# Why can't i properly retrieve data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a little problem with my simple firebase based app. Im trying to retrieve data from database like this:

```
public void readbuttonposition() {
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot buttonSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ButtonPosition buttonPosition = buttonSnapshot.getValue(ButtonPosition.class);
                    String user = buttonPosition.getbutton_position();

                    if (user == "1"){
                        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else if (user == "0"){
                        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

simply there are two buttons, each of them gives values: 0 and 1. As you can see, when `button2` is `VISIBLE` then `button3` is `GONE`. Thats allright everything is fine when im pressing the buttons. But when i want to restart the app and launch it again there's always `button2` visible, even when database 
button_position is valued as 1 which should make `button3` visible.. Here's a screenshot of firebase tree [image: screenshot]
and `DatabaseReference` path:
`database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user.getUid()).child("hours");`
im also retrieving `start_hour` this way and it works fine, so where i failed ? :D

@edit `ButtonPosition.class` code

```
public class ButtonPosition {
    String button_position;

    public ButtonPosition(){

    }

    public ButtonPosition(String button_position) {
        this.button_position = button_position;
    }
    public String getbutton_position(){
        return button_position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jave string comparison uses the `equals()` method not `==`.  Change `user == "X"` to `user.equals("X")`.  You should also post your `ButtonPosition` class to allow us to confirm that you have defined the getter/setter methods correctly.

Comment: @BobSnyder added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bob said in the comments when comparing strings you need to use the `equals()` method, so example: `if(users.equals("x")){...}`

and in your class add the setters:-

```
 public class ButtonPosition {
String button_position;

public ButtonPosition(){

}

public ButtonPosition(String button_position) {
    this.button_position = button_position;
}

 public void setButtonPosition(String button_position){
  this.button_position = button_position;
  }

public String getButtonPosition(){
    return button_position;
  }
}
```

Comment: when im using .equals(), i got NullPointerException, how can i solve this? :P

Comment: @Shizzle you need to do like this `String x="1";`. `String user="users";` `if(user.equals(x){...}`, so something like this

Comment: did it like u said, `String x = "1"` and `if (user.equals(x))` and still got NullPointException, honestly i dont really know how to solve that..

Comment: put a breakpoint next to this line `String user = buttonPosition.getbutton_position();`

Comment: String user = buttonPosition.getbutton_position()
so user is 0 or 1, right now its "0" in firebase

Comment: @Shizzle one of the variables is null.. change this in the model class `getbutton_position` to this `getButtonPosition`

Comment: still got NullPointerException after changing to `getButtonPosition`

Comment: you need to add a breakpoint next to user to be sure that it is retrieving. Put a condition before it `if(user!=null){ if(user.equal(x)){...}}` to see if it enters it and add Log.i("it entered:", user);

Comment: nothing happend, so i guess it didn't entered.

Comment: yes means it is not retrieving anything did you change this `buttonPosition.getButtonposition(); and in model class

Comment: Oh, previously i set it as `getButtonPosition`, now i changed it to `getButtonposition` and it works. Thank you very much Peter :)